# QFileInfo::isWritable() returning false at full permissions on windows 7

Tags: windows, qt, file-permissions

```
QFile file(filePath);
QFileInfo fileInfo(file);

file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite); //or WriteOnly

if(!fileInfo.isWritable())
{
    //Log error
}
else
{
    //Save to file
}
```

Problem is, filepath has full access, file is created and writable and yet isWritable() still return false. If I remove the write access check and simply write to file, writing is successful. QFile::open also returns true. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QFileInfo::isWritable()` is not for checking if a open file is writable, it's to check the permission of current user on the file. If all you want is the see if the open file operation succeeded, check the return value from the call `QFile::open()`. If it returns true then the file is ready to write. Do your error handling if it returns false.

I don't know why `isWritable()` fails in your case. It may be that Windows thinks the file has been open thus not writable from another `open()` call. If you really want to check permission, call `isWritable()` before opening the file.

Comment: If you check my post you will see that I already tried checking return value of `open()` (returns true). Just tried calling `isWritable()` before opening the file, still return false. If what you are saying is true, then my checks won't fail on `open()` call and everything will work as intended.

Comment: Seems it works, this solution is also Unix compatible (tested on Ubuntu and Kubuntu). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your program as administrator (with right click on it). Maybe this problem is caused by the UAC.

Comment: What is the full path of the file? What type of user is your account, normal user or administrator?